# Is a Singly Linked List Palindrome? JAVA

Tags: java, palindrome

It is the 234th question on LeetCode. The requirement for this task is to do it in O(n) time and O(1) space.
Definition for singly-linked list:

```
public class ListNode {
  int val;
  ListNode next;
  ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
```

}

If I write the function like this:

```
public class Solution {
public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
    List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
    while(head!=null){
        a.add(head.val);
        head = head.next;
    }
    for(int i=0, j=a.size()-1-i; i<j;){
        if(a.get(i) != a.get(j)){
            return false;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

This will return false if I try [128, 128], but it will return true if I try [127, 127]. I really do not know why. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Better post a minimal working example. One explanation for you observing wrong results would be: you **think** you are creating two "equal" lists (just using different numbers); but for some typo or whatever reason, you actually created lists that are not "equal". Thus: post all the code that we would need to reproduce your findings. Besides: your solution is definitely **not O(1) in space** - as you are creating a new list of length N.

Answer (score 0):

You're decrementing your loop counter but comparing it to your position counter. In other words, `while i<j` will only go through half the list.

so,

```
for( int i=0, j=a.size()-1; i<j ; ++i,--j ) {
    if ( a.get(i) != a.get(j) ) return false;
}
return true;
```

or, a little more obfuscated.

```
int i=0, j=a.size()-1;
while ( j > i && s[i] == s[j] ) { ++i; --j; }
return j<=i;
```

Comment: I think if I want to check is a singly linked list is palindrome, I will only need to go through half the list, because the other pointer will go through the other half.